# Can't install opensea-js with NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am currently using Node v14.16.0 and NPM v7.7.5 to install opensea-js as a dependency in a project.

I try to run the command `npm install --save opensea-js`, but I always end up with an error. I tried to clean NPM's cache, I have even reinstalled Node. I am on Windows. The stack trace is the following:

```
PS C:\multi-sender-opensea-js> npm install opensea-js
npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated bignumber.js@6.0.0: Custom ALPHABET bug fixed in v7.0.2
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.17.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\aguay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\aguay\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. 
It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.6: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated bignumber.js@6.0.0: Custom ALPHABET bug fixed in v7.0.2
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated buffer@4.9.1: This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v4.9.2 or newer
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated axios@0.17.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-yLrVA0M7LdolTGm4Eeh+SOffugSViZY9z/j5ctseZn5jTBJ5DAbyZ3vu1lQzHhbTSI2KpzEbKnfkT8LeNZSgog==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-u07PCyvWSxvmLPqnK7XBY4Ia7j6aTf5BmKy2dbT297VMIXLjOaZJfu4SMcoPF2GSCINCRlVwIOqaLuSJ5UZANA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ProjectWyvern/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-yLrVA0M7LdolTGm4Eeh+SOffugSViZY9z/j5ctseZn5jTBJ5DAbyZ3vu1lQzHhbTSI2KpzEbKnfkT8LeNZSgog==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for ethereumjs-abi@git+ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git (sha512-u07PCyvWSxvmLPqnK7XBY4Ia7j6aTf5BmKy2dbT297VMIXLjOaZJfu4SMcoPF2GSCINCRlVwIOqaLuSJ5UZANA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for bignumber.js@git+ssh://git@github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git (sha512-BPWfW6xhAeth4aWLg1g++Nrkn5KN+iqMsKQAdr/IywRCyBSjQ9JnyL49/Z3wgj2O/uW47RlYI2XPbJTKSoaVkw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN tarball tarball data for bignumber.js@git+ssh://git@github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git (sha512-BPWfW6xhAeth4aWLg1g++Nrkn5KN+iqMsKQAdr/IywRCyBSjQ9JnyL49/Z3wgj2O/uW47RlYI2XPbJTKSoaVkw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.9: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your 
dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! npm ERR! sha512-u07PCyvWSxvmLPqnK7XBY4Ia7j6aTf5BmKy2dbT297VMIXLjOaZJfu4SMcoPF2GSCINCRlVwIOqaLuSJ5UZANA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: 
wanted sha512-u07PCyvWSxvmLPqnK7XBY4Ia7j6aTf5BmKy2dbT297VMIXLjOaZJfu4SMcoPF2GSCINCRlVwIOqaLuSJ5UZANA== but got sha512-IA4lM/EAhHCmgR0uepm5PJ4b5/zcONaHZbBVlPbSbPT2+Mqbhj01vl11bupQPovWF6gHA3cDNkanFuaD3LTh5Q==. (13945 bytes)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     C:\Users\aguay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T20_11_41_637Z-debug.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aguay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T20_11_45_803Z-debug.log
```

Does someone have an idea how I can solve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well lucky for us the web3 only works with node v10.12.0

Answer (score 3):

Try switching to Node.js version 8.11 to make sure common crypto dependencies work.

Execute `nvm use`, if you have Node Version Manager.

Try installing [web3](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js)

from the [opensea-js npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opensea-js)